# Assure ACID concept when we use the modifier rollbackFor of Spring Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions

> Transaction processing is information processing in computer science
>   that is divided into individual, indivisible operations called
>   transactions. Each transaction must succeed or fail as a complete
>   unit; it can never be only partially complete.
>
> Transaction processing is designed to maintain a system’s Integrity in a known, consistent state, by ensuring that
>   interdependent operations on the system are either all completed
>   successfully or all canceled successfully. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing)

With the transactional management of Spring, we could use the modifier [rollbackFor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor--).

The principal purpose of this modifier is:

> Defines zero (0) or more exception classes, which must be subclasses
>   of Throwable, indicating which exception types must cause a
>   transaction rollback.

I found a method like this :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {SubscriptionException.class},  transactionManager = "txManager")
public void subscription(User user) throws SubscriptionException {
     operationA(user);
     operationB(user); // could throw a SubscriptionException
     operationC(user);
}
```

If `operationC` fails, changes made by `operationA` and  `operationB` will persist. IMHO, the property "[Atomicity](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity)" of [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) concept is broken on this transaction.

How assure ACID concept when we use the modifier `rollbackFor` of [Spring Transactional annotation](http://ttps://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)?

Comment: By setting rollbackFor to SubscriptionException.class, you precisely decided that no other exception than SubscriptionException constitutes a failure. So, if C "fails", it means is throws a SubscriptionException, and everything will rollback. If it throws another exception, then it doesn't fail, because only a SubscriptionException is a failure. If you want other exceptions to constitute a failure, then add them to rollbackFor.

Comment: *"If operationC fails, changes made by operationA and operationB will persist."* Not if the operations are transactional.

Comment: @JBNizet *"that no other exception than SubscriptionException constitutes a failure"* Not true. Javadoc of [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) says: *"If no rules are relevant to the exception, it will be treated like DefaultTransactionAttribute (**rolling back on `RuntimeException` and `Error` but not on checked exceptions**)"*. --- Since `SubscriptionException ` is the only possible checked exception, that code will roll back on all exceptions.

Comment: @Andreas if you don't specify rollbackFor, then runtime exceptions and errors cause a rollback. If you do, then the exceptions specified in rollbackFor cause a rollback.

Comment: @JBNizet `rollbackFor` *adds* a rule. Then *"If no rules are relevant to the exception, ..."* means that the default rules to roll back on `RuntimeException` and `Error` still applies. If you don't want all or some RuntimeExceptions to roll back, you need to name them with `noRollbackFor`.

Comment: You may be right (the documentation isn't very clear about that). That doesn't change much to my reasoning anyway. It's up to you to decide what constitutes a failure, and once you have decided, a failure will cause a rollback.

Comment: You're right indeed: the default rules apply even if rollbackFor is specified

Comment: @Andreas the operations of the exemple are not transactional . If operation C throw a RuntimeException or Error, do you confirm that default rules apply and rollback of operation A and B is executed even if rollbackFor is specified ? If is the case that assure the définition of transaction where each element must succeed or fail as a complete unit; it can never be only partially complete.

Comment: @JesusZavarce As I said, it depends on what the operations are doing, i.e. whether they interact with the transaction manager so their actions can be rolled back if the transaction is rolled back. If they perform JDBC operations using the Spring framework, then they are transactional in nature. If they perform e.g. web service calls, then they are not implicitly transactional in nature, because Spring doesn't know how to undo a web service call.